# SQL Server 2012 BCP returns bad data with guid parameter in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, guid, bcp

I am currently trying to run a `bcp` command from within a C# class. It should accomplish grabbing binary data from a table, then saving it to a hard drive. If I set `CaseId` outside of my command, I will get 0 kb documents saved to my hard drive. If I hard code `CaseId` (by this I mean grab a Guid from my table that I know exists and shove it into the `bcp` statement), the documents will be saved with all of their data to my hard drive.

Additionally, I have tried inserting the `CaseId` into the command itself with the Guid that is passed into my function that is running this code, for example:

```
...cd.DocumentId = d.Id WHERE cd.CaseId = '" + CaseId + "' \"...
```

Here is my command as it sits currently in code:

```
var sql = "";
sql = sql + "DECLARE  @Command       VARCHAR(4000), ";
sql = sql + "@Filename VARCHAR(150), ";
sql = sql + "@DocId uniqueidentifier ";
sql = sql + "DECLARE curDoc CURSOR  FOR  ";
sql = sql + "SELECT ";
sql = sql + "d.Filename, ";
sql = sql + "d.Id ";
sql = sql + "FROM   oregon2.dbo.Doc2 d ";
sql = sql + "JOIN   oregon2.dbo.CaseDocuments cd on cd.DocumentId = d.Id ";
sql = sql + "WHERE  cd.CaseId = @CaseId ";
sql = sql + "OPEN curDoc ";
sql = sql + "FETCH NEXT FROM curDoc ";
sql = sql + "INTO ";
sql = sql + "@Filename, ";
sql = sql + "@DocId ";
sql = sql + "WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) ";
sql = sql + "BEGIN ";
sql = sql + "SET @Command = 'bcp \"SELECT d.Content FROM oregon2.dbo.Doc2 d JOIN oregon2.dbo.CaseDocuments cd on cd.DocumentId = d.Id WHERE cd.CaseId = ''@CaseId'' \" queryout \"C:\\temp\\' + convert(varchar(50), @CaseId) + '\\' + convert(varchar(50), @DocId) + '\\' + @Filename + '\" -T -n -S.' ";
sql = sql + "PRINT @Command ";
sql = sql + "EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command ";
sql = sql + "FETCH NEXT FROM curDoc ";
sql = sql + "INTO ";
sql = sql + "@Filename, ";
sql = sql + "@DocId ";
sql = sql + "END ";
sql = sql + "CLOSE curDoc ";
sql = sql + "DEALLOCATE curDoc ";
```

I am running Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

Any help would be much appreciated. The hair-pulling is about to begin.

Comment: You **do know** that you could write this as `string sql = @"....."` and then have your **entire** statement, even spread out over multiple lines - inside those double quotes?!?!?! This would be **(a)** **much easier** to read, and **(b)** would prevent a new string from being allocated every time you add another line of SQL to your existing `sql` .....

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, I did know this - and previously it was written that way. For whatever reason I could not get the syntax right in the bcp command until I wrote it out like this.

Comment: What is output of the `"PRINT @Command "` statement?  Have you tried capturing that and then executing it from DOS yourself?  This would be my next step.

Comment: The input line is too long :/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who was wondering here is the final code, working code:

```
            var sql = "";
            sql = sql + "DECLARE  @Command       VARCHAR(4000), ";
            sql = sql + "@Filename VARCHAR(150), ";
            sql = sql + "@DocId uniqueidentifier ";
            sql = sql + "DECLARE curDoc CURSOR  FOR  ";
            sql = sql + "SELECT ";
            sql = sql + "d.Filename, ";
            sql = sql + "d.Id ";
            sql = sql + "FROM   oregon2.dbo.Doc2 d ";
            sql = sql + "JOIN   oregon2.dbo.CaseDocuments cd on cd.DocumentId = d.Id ";
            sql = sql + "WHERE  cd.CaseId = @CaseId ";
            sql = sql + "OPEN curDoc ";
            sql = sql + "FETCH NEXT FROM curDoc ";
            sql = sql + "INTO ";
            sql = sql + "@Filename, ";
            sql = sql + "@DocId ";
            sql = sql + "WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) ";
            sql = sql + "BEGIN ";
            sql = sql + "SET @Command = 'bcp \"SELECT d.Content FROM oregon2.dbo.Doc2 d JOIN oregon2.dbo.CaseDocuments cd on cd.DocumentId = d.Id WHERE cd.CaseId = '''+ convert(varchar(50), @CaseId) +''' \" queryout \"C:\\temp\\' + convert(varchar(50), @CaseId) + '\\' + convert(varchar(50), @DocId) + '\\' + @Filename + '\" -T -n -S.' ";
            sql = sql + "PRINT @Command ";
            sql = sql + "EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command ";
            sql = sql + "FETCH NEXT FROM curDoc ";
            sql = sql + "INTO ";
            sql = sql + "@Filename, ";
            sql = sql + "@DocId ";
            sql = sql + "END ";
            sql = sql + "CLOSE curDoc ";
            sql = sql + "DEALLOCATE curDoc ";
```

There needed to be an additional escape routine and also a conversion to a varchar on my CaseId.